# Mentioning isolated effect using alone/lone

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I was explaining a physical phenomenon where an element produces an effect (say pressure), which is combined with the pressure induced by another phenomenon. The writing in my case demands special mentioning for the original pressure induced by the element. For that, I tried this:

```
1. The element alone induced pressure
```

The intention was to distinguish the original pressure induced by the element from the combined pressure. But Practical English usage (Micheal Swan) quotes such usages as wrong and suggests "lone" in such scenarios. Therefore,

```
2. The element lone induced pressure
```

Should be fine, but the above-mentioned examples are not seen on the internet. The word "original" does not fit in the case, because the readers may misinterpret it. Welcoming suggestions.

Comment: This is a case of pushing too many technical words together. Going for efficiency can sacrifice effectiveness. By allowing the reader to take a breath, I get good results with: *the pressure induced by the element alone*. Then I contrast that with *the pressure induced by the element in combination*.

Comment: 'The element alone ...' is ambiguous, meaning 'nothing else was necessary ... it did it on its own' or 'it was the only thing that did'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "lone" in this fashion, anyway, the reason being essentially that this is an adjective you use before nouns only; as well, the fact that it is a rather literary term makes its use in a scientific text somewhat bizarre.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lone?q=lone)) **lone**[only before noun] ​without any other people or things
> SYNONYM solitary
> ♦ a lone sailor crossing the Atlantic
> ♦ The attack was carried out by a lone gunman in a crowded shopping centre.

- the pressure induced by the *sole* element …

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sole_1?q=sole)) **sole** [only before noun] ​ only; single
> ♦ the sole surviving member of the family
> ♦ My sole reason for coming here was to see you.

Comment: Even the Lone Ranger wasn't alone, thanks to Tonto.

Comment: This is not a suitable question / answer for a site aimed at linguists.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may have misunderstood the gist of Swan's advice in *Practical English Usage*. Here is what he says about *alone* and *lone* in section 42 of the 1995 edition of his book:

> **42 alone, lonely, lonesome** and **lone**
>
> *Alone* suggests that a person or thing is separate – there are no others around. *Lonely* (and informal US *lonesome*) refers to unhappiness caused by being alone. [Examples omitted.] *Alone* is not used before a noun (see 15.3 [which says, "Some adjectives beginning with *a-*, and a few others, are used mainly in predicative position – after a verb. Common examples: afloat, *afraid*, *alight*, *alike*, *alive*, *alone*, *asleep*, *awake*."]) *Lone* and *solitary* can be used instead; *lone* is rather literary. [Example:] The only green thing was a ***lone/solitary*** pine tree.

Swan says flatly that you shouldn't use *alone* as a modifier in front of a noun or noun phrase such as *pine tree*. But in the phrase "The element alone induced pressure," *alone* doesn't appear before the noun (in this case, *element*); rather, it appears after the noun but before the verb—and in this position, *alone* has been standard in idiomatic English for several centuries at least. For example, an Ngram search for the phrase "I alone can" for the period 1650–2050 yields the following chart:

[image]

If you're interested in seeing specific Google Books examples of that phrase in real-world literary use, click the links beneath the [graph version of the chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+alone+can&year_start=1650&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20alone%20can%3B%2Cc0) here.

It would be incorrect to say, "*Alone* is used only in predicative position"—but in fact what Swan says is that *alone* is "used mainly in predicative position – after a verb." Obviously *mainly* is not the same as *only*. Your wording "The element alone induced pressure" is perfectly good English.

*Lone*, on the other hand, sounds natural as a modifier preceding a noun or noun phrase (as in the "lone pine tree" example that Swan mentions)—but it doesn't do well as a modifier after a noun (as in your "The element lone induced pressure" example). No native English speaker would use that particular wording.

Comment: Dear Sven, it was quite helpful, though I am now afraid that my question was not enough clear. "Induced" was not used as a verb, but as a modifier, something like element-induced pressure. Such usages are common in my research domain, for example: "shock-induced transformation" (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=shock-induced+pressure&btnG=)